# Running google cloudprint on boot

Tags: debian, boot, python

I use [this Python script](https://github.com/armooo/cloudprint) on my Debian based Guru Plug to make it work as a print server for Google Cloudprint. With this I can print from my Android devices using apps like `PrinterShare` or `Cloud Print`. It works perfectly.

However, I have to start the script manually if I for some reason have to reboot the plug computer. If would like to have it start automatically on boot, but so far I haven't succeded.

In `/etc/rc.local` I have this line:

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/cloudprint -d
```

Using `pgrep` I can see that the script is running upon boot but it does not work. And redirecting output messages to a log file reveals that it ask for my Google username.

Normally it does not ask for authentification as this is stored in `/root/.cloudprintauth`. But obviously, when running from rc.local it is not able to read or find the file.

So my question is:

How do I enable the script to be able to find/read the authentification file when run from rc.local?

Comment: Have you read: [Install Google Cloud Print on a Linux server](https://support.google.com/chromeos/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2616503)?

Comment: Yes, but I think it is overkill to install Chrome on a tiny little server like the Guru Plug with limited resources. The python script works fine except I don't know how to make it start properly on boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the script has the *auth* file path [hard-coded](https://github.com/armooo/cloudprint/blob/master/cloudprint/cloudprint.py#L30) relying on the shell expansion of the home directory:

```
self.auth_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.cloudprintauth')
```

My recommendation is that you patch the file by changing that line to an absolute path:

```
self.auth_path = os.path.expanduser('/root/.cloudprintauth')
```

Hopefully it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a set of packages for Debian that will do this for you.

https://github.com/davesteele/cloudprint-debian

Install and run "service cloudprintd login" as root.

Comment: Thanks! I actually need to install the cloudprint script on my Raspi, so I will try this.